# NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint error when UITableViewHeaderFooterView is reused

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I'm getting the following error after a call to `insertSections:withRowAnimation:` and `endUpdates`. The error concerns autolayout in my custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` but only when the header is reused by `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:`. First time it works fine with no errors.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
...
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10b77f9f0 V:|-(8)-[UIView:0x10b77d0f0]   (Names: '|':WYBDetailHeaderView:0x10b77e620 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10b77cac0 h=--& v=--& V:[WYBDetailHeaderView:0x10b77e620(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10b77fa40 V:[UIView:0x10b77d0f0]-(>=4)-|   (Names: '|':WYBDetailHeaderView:0x10b77e620 )>"
)
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10b77fa40 V:[UIView:0x10b77d0f0]-(>=4)-|   (Names: '|':WYBDetailHeaderView:0x10b77e620 )>
```

There is a similar error for the horizontal constraints. The problem is that a `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` appears for both width and height set to zero. However, once the animation completes the header layout is correct and looks fine.

I have followed the advice in this related question with no luck: [UITableViewHeaderFooterView subclass with auto layout and section reloading won't work well together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581550/uitableviewheaderfooterview-subclass-with-auto-layout-and-section-reloading-won)

Has anyone encountered something similar before?

Is there something I can do to avoid the warning?

This is the implementation in my `UITableView`:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    WYBDetailHeaderView *header = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"WYB"];
    [header setupWithTitle:@"Title" subtitle:@"Subtitle"];
    return header;
}
```

And the implementation of WYBDetailHeaderView (it uses a NIB which I register with `registerNib:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:`):

```
- (void)setupWithTitle:(NSString *)title subtitle:(NSString *)subtitle
{
    // Set labels.
    self.titleLabel.text = title.uppercaseString;
    self.subtitleLabel.text = subtitle;

    // Clear image.
    self.headerImageView.image = nil;
    self.emptyImage = NO;

    // Mark for layout update.
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    self.prototype = NO;
    self.emptyImage = NO;
}

- (void)updateConstraints
{
    // See if there is an image.
    if (self.emptyImage || self.headerImageView.image) {
        self.imageWidthConstraint.constant = 20;
        self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = 20;
        self.imageTitleSpaceConstraint.constant = 8;
    }
    else {
        self.imageWidthConstraint.constant = 0;
        self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
        self.imageTitleSpaceConstraint.constant = 0;
    }

    [super updateConstraints];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.titleLabel.frame);
    self.subtitleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.subtitleLabel.frame);
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Comment: Show me your implementation of tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: method and prepareForReuse:

Comment: Thanks @bilobatum I have edited the post with the implementation of both functions you requested.

Comment: Actually I wonder if my problem is related to something similar in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581550/uitableviewheaderfooterview-subclass-with-auto-layout-and-section-reloading-won. Sadly none of the suggestions there have helped in my case.

Comment: With some more testing I have discovered that the error is definitely caused by the call to `insertSections:withRowAnimation:` and then `endUpdates`. And definitely only when the header is reused. There are no visible problems with the layout during animation, and when the animation is complete the layout is correct. I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: I have similar problems with a custom UIView used as UITableView section header, but only throws the Exception when called - tableView:reloadSection: (which I use to "collapse" a section of tableView cells)

Comment: I've just run in to this. I'm only finding it with testing on iOS 8.1 – my testing until now had been 8.3, where I don't get the problem. Seems like no answers though?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar error and making use of estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath caused it.