# How am I suggesting a TableViewCell height of zero?

Tags: nslayoutconstraint, xcode9

I have a tableView with some static cells. It's set to automatically calculate the row height. The bottom most button is in a cell with a height constraint along with top, bottom, leading, and trailing. All constraints are done in the interface builder with no warnings or errors showing for the scene.

[image: Button Placement]

Yet I'm getting this warning when I run the app and display the scene:

```
2018-01-16 08:00:40.149994-0500 Reference App[9176:1864272] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd01dd16530 UIButton:0x7fd01dd171a0'Reset Data'.height == 44   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd01dd31860 V:|-(0)-[UIButton:0x7fd01dd171a0'Reset Data']   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd01dd314c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd01dd31bb0 V:[UIButton:0x7fd01dd171a0'Reset Data']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd01dd314c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd01d8516c0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd01dd314c0.height == 44   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd01dd16530 UIButton:0x7fd01dd171a0'Reset Data'.height == 44   (active)>
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the error. As suggested at this link [What is NSLayoutConstraint "UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height" and how should I go about forcing it to recalculate cleanly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059443), I tried lowering the priority of the height constraint to 999 and it didn't fix the issue. I also gave an estimated height of 44 and it reduced the output to simply the warning about a zero height.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is NSLayoutConstraint "UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height" and how should I go about forcing it to recalculate cleanly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059443/what-is-nslayoutconstraint-uiview-encapsulated-layout-height-and-how-should-i)

Comment: In short: set the priority of the height constraint to 999.

Comment: @the4kman, tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Okay. The zero height warning must have been from a different cell. I make sure I had top to bottom constraints on the other cells and found one was missing the appropriate constraints. Fixing this made the zero height error go away.